# Defining the model in typescript

Tags: typescript

How can I represent the data model in typescript for the below structure? The key-values after `id` (like `a1`,`a2`) are dynamic, which means there can be different key-value there.

```
    {
        name: 'SampleName',
        description: 'Sample description',
        id: '_3434',

        a1:'abc',
        a2:'xyz'
    }
```

Trying something like below doesn't make sense, since we don't have `others` in the data.

```
interface TestData{
name:string;
description:string;
id:string;

others:any;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a type that has some known properties and a index signature for dynamic data. The index signature needs to be compatible with all properties, but in this case you only have strings so it isn't a problem:

```
interface TestData {
    name: string;
    description: string;
    id: string;

    [name: string]: string
}
```

You should be careful with such types, they will allow indexing by anything so this will not throw any compiler error:

```
 declare let a: TestData;
 a.notHere // ts is ok with this since the index signature is there
```